# How do I do symmetric encryption? I'm having problems

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I tried this way, but I do not understand what is wrong. I include a user, and in the CMD, putting in the code a print, there it printa codified, already in the database it becomes visible.

```
import sqlite
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def incluir(self):
    if self.validation():
        query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios_arduino VALUES (NULL, ?,?)'
        chave = Fernet.generate_key()
        f = Fernet(chave)
        f_pass = f.encrypt(self.senha.get().encode())
        print(f_pass)
        parameters = (self.user.get(), self.senha.get())
        try:
            self.run_query(query,parameters)
            self.msgG['text']='Usuário {} incluído com Sucesso!'.format(self.user.get())
            self.user.delete(0, END)
            self.senha.delete(0, END)
        except:
            self.msg['text'] = 'Usuário já existente, tente outro!'    
            pass
    else:
        self.msg['text'] = 'Favor inserir usuário e senha nos campos!'
```

Comment: You are not using f_pass as a query parameter, you're using the return value of self.senha.get() directly.

Comment: Resolved, thank very much!